# Setstate if fetch result is different

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from some url each second. If data is different than data inside my state, I want to update that state and rerender, and if data is same I do not want to do anything

First I tried most obvious thing, to set interval in `useEffect` on mount, but it do not work since state always return initial value which is obvious.

Second I created two states, one that holds data and other temp one, then I update temp state and on its `useEffect` I compare values. It does work but I still got rerender when updating that temp state, and whole point was to not have unnecessary rerender.

Third thing I tried is holding that temp data inside variable or ref, but `useEffect` is not working on them.

Here is last code I tried with ref so you get idea of what I am trying to do:

```
const MyComp = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const tempDataRef = useRef([])

    useEffect(() => {
        apiFetch().then((returnedArray) => {
            tempDataRef.current = returnedArray
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        // in this solution using ref, this useeffect is not firing
        if(JSON.stringify(tempDataRef.current) != JSON.stringify(data)) {
            setData(tempDataRef.current)
        }
    }, [tempDataRef.current])

    return (
        <div>
            {JSON.stringify(data)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Why not `setState` your `returnedArray` in your first `useEffect`  directly? It looks the behavior is same as your current code.

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat because then component gets rerendered, and I want to avoid rerendering if data is same

Answer (score 0):

> whole point was to not have unnecessary rerender.

tl;dr - it's not possible. Component has to be aware that the *data* has changed.

`setData(tempDataRef.current)` code does not fire at all, since `useEffect` does not listen to `useRef` updates.

You have two options - either store the *data* in the state, or keep the `useRef` but then you will have to apply some interval to check  if the *data* has changed and if so - re-render the component. But of course this is pointless, because you will end up with unnecessary re-renders.

If you are worried about performance drop caused by this *"extra"* re-render when fetching the *data* you can always *memoize* your children so they won't re-render unnecessarily.

Comment: Exactly, I am worried about re-render because it happens each second (or may even faster if I set it lower). What do you mean with "memorize my children"

Comment: @AleksaRistic Wrap children with `React.memo` and make sure to wrap drilled functions with `useCallback`.